# if $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ show that $(a) + (b) = (d)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I've got the basic idea of this proof just not sure how to write it formally.

If $d = gcd(a, b) $, then $ d = au + bv $, where $a$ and $b$ are not both zero. $(d)$ is the set of all multiplies of $d$.
So, if $ z\in (d)$ then $z = dk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, since 
$dk = a(uk) + b(vk) $, dk divides the multiples of a and b

How, to transition this formally to state that $ (d) = (a) + (b) $? Or can I just conclude at this point that $(d) = (a) + (b) $ Since every multiple of $d$ is a sum of some elements in $(a)$ and $(b)$ as stated above? With the sum of two ideals, $ (a) + (b) $ = { $a + b $ | $ a\in (a), b \in (b)$ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your observation gives the inclusion $(d) \subset (a) + (b)$. For the other one, simply one has that as $d|a, d|b$ to get the result and thus the equality of sets.